# How to read English words, written in cirilic?

Tags: cipher, language

I met this picture on [Youtube](https://youtu.be/uxWdmi4vsaU?t=203). There are Cyrillic letters, which doesn't fit into any Cyrillic language I've seen.
First, I thought it is just random letters combinations, but then I noticed that, applying some imagination, I can see English words there, like "SOVIET", "UNION", "CITIES", if I replace:

> "Ф" -> "O"
>    "Э" -> "E"
>    "Ц" -> "U"
>    "И" -> "N"

But still, I can't read most of the words, starting from "ЯЭ" and "ТФЦЯ". Can someone help me to read all the words on this picture?
[image]

Comment: How is this a puzzle?

Comment: I read everything naturally on my first try, is there a catch?

Comment: @Rubio, how it is not? tag descriptions on this site: "A cipher is a simple method of modifying messages to make them unreadable, but still possible to recover."  "built around a peculiarity of the English language."

Comment: Gotta like the "This machine conquers fascists" and the "wait 4 months in line for tickets now!" haha.

Comment: There's no *puzzle*.  It's a (**very**) straightforward exercise in reading.  The part you missed, maybe, is the words "to make them unreadable" - this is perfectly readable without any particular effort, as the substitutions trivially resemble the letters they replace; this isn't a cipher, it's a "cute" Cyrillicization of letters in English words to give a Russian feel to an otherwise pedestrian ad for some band reunion tour.  There's no puzzle here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no puzzle here.

Comment: @Rubio, the thing is - I can't read it. So most of the words here in fact unreadable for me. Is puzzleSE only for those who know solutions and expect to challenge the others? According to help center it is not.

Comment: [Related picture](http://www.geenstijl.nl/archives/images/gehecktscreenshot.png).

Comment: It's actually *harder* to read if you *do* know the Cyrillic alphabet.

Comment: I voted to reopen. Although it is very straightforward for the majority here (including me), this is a serious question from the OP. I don't know if the OP maybe has some form of dyslexia or something which could make it a lot harder but that's not the point. It's a genuine question and it is actually a sort of substitution cipher and therefore suited for this website

Comment: I think the outcome we've actually got -- the question is closed but helpful readers have in fact answered it -- may be the best one :-). Incidentally, is this a real poster for a real band? There's no obvious band name or anything.

Comment: Looks more like a meme to me. Doomsayers and all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Continuing on the answer of J.A.K.:

> Soviet (re)union tour
>  10 cities
>  no classes
>  one worldwide revolution

We see dates:

> 25/10 Leningrad 31/10 Moscow 2/11 Kiev 4/11 Minsk 5/11 Warsaw 6/11 Instanbul 7/11 Berlin 11/11 Paris 13/11 London 19/11 Washington DC

In the picture of the country we see:

> This machine
>  Conquers fascists

And in the setlist we see:

> Opium for the masses
>  Capitalist excess
>  Bourgeoisie misery
>  October dreams
>  Rise of the proletariat
>  Hammer and sickle time
>  Continuous Revolution
>  End of History

Ending with the note:

> Wait 4 months in line for tickets now!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a puzzle, letters are substituted for their cyrillic lookalikes.

> Soviet (re)union tour
>
> 10 cities
>
> no classes
>
> one worldwide revolution

Comment: Well, it is a puzzle. Just a very easy one. Unless there is a catch.